# Using mlr package for 10-fold cross-validation on svyglm

Tags: r, cross-validation, survey, mlr

I am an R newbie. I am using R to explore how I can do a 10-fold cross-validation on svyglm for machine learning. None of the popular R packages such as caret, mlr support svyglm. I want to use mlr's makeresamplesinstance to create sample folds/splits and use that in a function/loop for cross-validation on svyglm. My goal is to predict based on cross-validated estimates and produce mean missclassification error and auc from the predictions.

EDIT: Building an mlr learner would be the ideal solution. any help with that will be appreciated too.

Here's a reproducible example:

```
library(twang)
library(survey)
library(mlr)
set.seed(1)

data(lalonde)

tsk1 = makeClassifTask(id = "re78", data = Aids2[, c("age", "educ", "black", "hispan")], target = "re78")


merge_10CV1 = makeResampleDesc("CV", iters = 10L, stratify = TRUE)
merge10CV<-makeResampleInstance(merge_10CV1, tsk1)


ps.lalonde <- ps(treat ~ age + educ + black + hispan + nodegree + married + re74 + re75,
 data = lalonde)
lalonde$w <- get.weights(ps.lalonde, stop.method="es.mean")
design.ps <- svydesign(ids=~1, weights=~w, data=lalonde)

#how do I use 10 fold cross-validation here?
glm1 <- svyglm(re78 ~ age + educ + black + hispan, design=design.ps)

summary(glm1)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You would have to implement svyglm as an mlr learner. There's some information on that in the [mlr tutorial](https://mlr-org.github.io/mlr-tutorial/devel/html/create_learner/index.html).

Comment: Thanks! I did go over the learner tutorial. I am not fluent enough to create a learner yet.